# Reading logs using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, logging

I have a .txt file contains requests logs in the following format:

```
time_namelookup: 0,121668 
time_connect: 0,460643 
time_pretransfer: 0,460755 
time_redirect: 0,000000 
time_starttransfer: 0,811697 
time_total: 0,811813 
-------------
time_namelookup: 0,121665 
time_connect: 0,460643 
time_pretransfer: 0,460355 
time_redirect: 0,000000 
time_starttransfer: 0,813697 
time_total: 0,811853 
-------------
time_namelookup: 0,121558 
time_connect: 0,463243 
time_pretransfer: 0,460755 
time_redirect: 0,000000 
time_starttransfer: 0,911697 
time_total: 0,811413
```

I want to create a list of values for each category so I thought regular expression could relevant in that case.

```
import re

'''
In this exmaple, I save only the 'time_namelookup' parameter
The same logic adapted for other parameters.
'''

namelookup = []
with open('shaghai_if_config_test.txt', 'r') as fh:
     for line in fh.readlines():
         number_match = re.match('([+-]?([0-9]*[,])?[0-9]+)',line)
         namelookup_match = re.match('^time_namelookup:', line)
         if namelookup_match and number_match:
             num = number_match.group(0)
             namelookup.append(num)
             continue
```

I find this logic quite complicated as I have to execute two regex matches. Moreover, the `number_match` parameter doesn't match the line, while `^time_namelookup: ([+-]?([0-9]*[,])?[0-9]+)` works fine

I looking for experienced advice for the described procedure. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have designed a fine expression, we would maybe slightly modify that to:

```
(time_(?:namelookup|connect|pretransfer|redirect|starttransfer|total))\s*:\s*([+-]?(?:\d*,)?\d+)
```

#### Test with `re.findall`:

```
import re

regex = r"(time_(?:namelookup|connect|pretransfer|redirect|starttransfer|total))\s*:\s*([+-]?(?:\d*,)?\d+)"

test_str = ("time_namelookup: 0,121668 \n"
    "time_connect: 0,460643 \n"
    "time_pretransfer: 0,460755 \n"
    "time_redirect: 0,000000 \n"
    "time_starttransfer: 0,811697 \n"
    "time_total: 0,811813 \n")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
[('time_namelookup', '0,121668'), ('time_connect', '0,460643'), ('time_pretransfer', '0,460755'), ('time_redirect', '0,000000'), ('time_starttransfer', '0,811697'), ('time_total', '0,811813')]
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`:

```
import re

regex = r"(time_(?:namelookup|connect|pretransfer|redirect|starttransfer|total))\s*:\s*([+-]?(?:\d*,)?\d+)"

test_str = ("time_namelookup: 0,121668 \n"
    "time_connect: 0,460643 \n"
    "time_pretransfer: 0,460755 \n"
    "time_redirect: 0,000000 \n"
    "time_starttransfer: 0,811697 \n"
    "time_total: 0,811813 \n"
    "-------------\n"
    "time_namelookup: 0,121665 \n"
    "time_connect: 0,460643 \n"
    "time_pretransfer: 0,460355 \n"
    "time_redirect: 0,000000 \n"
    "time_starttransfer: 0,813697 \n"
    "time_total: 0,811853 \n"
    "-------------\n"
    "time_namelookup: 0,121558 \n"
    "time_connect: 0,463243 \n"
    "time_pretransfer: 0,460755 \n"
    "time_redirect: 0,000000 \n"
    "time_starttransfer: 0,911697 \n"
    "time_total: 0,811413 ")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nocFgW/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make it lot easier with a loop over a list holding left side of the capture:

```
import re

lst = ['time_namelookup', 'time_connect', 'time_pretransfer', 'time_redirect', 'time_starttransfer', 'time_total']

result = []
for x in lst:
    result.append(re.findall(f'{x}: (.*)', s))

print(result)
```

where `s` is your text file data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply `itertools.groupby` and `str.split` for a non-regex solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in groupby(data, key=lambda x:x.startswith('time'))]
results = [dict(i.split(': ') for i in b) for a, b in new_data if a]
```

Output:

```
[{'time_namelookup': '0,121668 ', 'time_connect': '0,460643 ', 'time_pretransfer': '0,460755 ', 'time_redirect': '0,000000 ', 'time_starttransfer': '0,811697 ', 'time_total': '0,811813 '}, 
 {'time_namelookup': '0,121665 ', 'time_connect': '0,460643 ', 'time_pretransfer': '0,460355 ', 'time_redirect': '0,000000 ', 'time_starttransfer': '0,813697 ', 'time_total': '0,811853 '}, 
 {'time_namelookup': '0,121558 ', 'time_connect': '0,463243 ', 'time_pretransfer': '0,460755 ', 'time_redirect': '0,000000 ', 'time_starttransfer': '0,911697 ', 'time_total': '0,811413 '}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is that simple, here's another idea - read the file with a CSV parser, using colon as the delimiter. Example:

```
import csv
import itertools
from pprint import pprint as print

file = 'log.txt'
with open(file) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=':')
    # filter out delimiter lines
    rows = [r for r in reader if len(r) == 2]
    # group pairs by first element to a dict of lists
    grouped = {k: [x[1] for x in v] for k, v
               in itertools.groupby(sorted(rows), key=lambda x: x[0])}
    print(grouped)
```

will give you:

```
{'time_connect': [' 0.460643 ', ' 0.460643 ', ' 0.463243 '],
 'time_namelookup': [' 0.121558 ', ' 0.121665 ', ' 0.121668 '],
 'time_pretransfer': [' 0.460355 ', ' 0.460755 ', ' 0.460755 '],
 'time_redirect': [' 0.000000 ', ' 0.000000 ', ' 0.000000 '],
 'time_starttransfer': [' 0.811697 ', ' 0.813697 ', ' 0.911697 '],
 'time_total': [' 0.811413 ', ' 0.811813 ', ' 0.811853 ']}
```

If you need further processing, do it in dict comprehension, e.g. for parsing numbers:

```
grouped = {k: [float(x[1].strip()) for x in v] for k, v
           in itertools.groupby(sorted(rows), key=lambda x: x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'time_connect': [0.460643, 0.460643, 0.463243],
 'time_namelookup': [0.121558, 0.121665, 0.121668],
 'time_pretransfer': [0.460355, 0.460755, 0.460755],
 'time_redirect': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'time_starttransfer': [0.811697, 0.813697, 0.911697],
 'time_total': [0.811413, 0.811813, 0.811853]}
```

#### `pandas`

If you happen to have `pandas` around, you can use it for reading the log as CSV, this will save you the fuzz of parsing and grouping data. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('log.txt', delimiter=':', header=None, names=['Name', 'Num']).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

will output the data parsed and ready to use:

```
                  Name       Num
0      time_namelookup  0.121668
1         time_connect  0.460643
2     time_pretransfer  0.460755
3        time_redirect  0.000000
4   time_starttransfer  0.811697
5           time_total  0.811813
6      time_namelookup  0.121665
7         time_connect  0.460643
8     time_pretransfer  0.460355
9        time_redirect  0.000000
10  time_starttransfer  0.813697
11          time_total  0.811853
12     time_namelookup  0.121558
13        time_connect  0.463243
14    time_pretransfer  0.460755
15       time_redirect  0.000000
16  time_starttransfer  0.911697
17          time_total  0.811413
```

Now do whatever you intend to do with the data, e.g. reshape the data frame for a more structured view:

```
df['chunk'] = df.index // df.Name.unique().size
print(df.pivot(values='Num', columns='Name', index='chunk'))

# Output:

Name   time_connect  time_namelookup  time_pretransfer  time_redirect  time_starttransfer  time_total
chunk                                                                                                
0          0.460643         0.121668          0.460755            0.0            0.811697    0.811813
1          0.460643         0.121665          0.460355            0.0            0.813697    0.811853
2          0.463243         0.121558          0.460755            0.0            0.911697    0.811413
```

calculate stats for selected times:

```
print(df[df.Name == 'time_total'].describe())

# Output:

            Num
count  3.000000
mean   0.811693
std    0.000243
min    0.811413
25%    0.811613
50%    0.811813
75%    0.811833
max    0.811853
```

etc.